# equivalent statement for positive definitiveness

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

In this lecture (https://engineering.purdue.edu/~ragu/confpapers/Bal302-talk.pdf) page $14$, it is said that for a real matrix $A$ and a symmetric positive definite matrix $P$ the statement
$$ A^T P + P A < 0 $$ is equivalent with 
$$ Q A^T + A Q < 0 $$ with $Q = P^{-1}$. I am unable to prove this. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Multiply by $Q$ on both sides? After all $M<0 \iff B^TMB<0$ for any invertible $B$.

Comment: great, thank you. that usefull equivalence was missing to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given that 
$$A^T P + P A < 0$$
which means that for any $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$, you have
$$z^T( A^T P + P A) z < 0$$
Since $Q$ is full rank, this means that if $y$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$, then so does $z = Qy$. So, for any $y$ the following is true
$$y^TQ^T( A^T P + P A) Qy < 0$$
Since $Q$  is symmetric (because its inverse $P$ is symmetric)
$$y^TQ( A^T P + P A) Qy < 0$$
or
$$y^T( QA^T PQ + QP AQ) y < 0$$
But $PQ = QP = I$ so
$$y^T( QA^T +  AQ) y < 0$$ 
which is true for all $y$, hence
$$ QA^T +  AQ < 0$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as mentioned by Rahul, multiplying both sides by $P^{-1}$ already gives the desired matrix. This I did my self. However, I couldn't assert the fact that it is negative definite. But that equivalence he mentioned solved my problem $x^TMx < 0 $ for all $x$, let $x = yB$ hence $y^TB^T M B y < 0$ If $B$ has full rank that means that the transformation $y = B^{-1}x$ covers all $\mathbb{R}$ hence we are done. However, your solution is ... pretty much the same, hence I will accept it.